# Use variable inside bash brace expansion

Tags: bash, variable, brace-expansion, bash-expansion

I have a program that generates a variable number of pictures, ordered like that:
`1.jpg, 2.jpg [...] 10.jpg..etc`

I can't use `*.jpg` as input because the 10 will be processed before 2, 3, etc. so I want to use:

```
convert page_{1..$N}.jpg out.pdf
```

but does not work. How should the command be?

Answer (score 5):

You could store the filenames in an array, generating them with `seq`:

```
pages=( $(printf 'page_%d.jpg\n' $(seq $N)) )
convert "${pages[@]}" out.pdf
```

Comment: seq is not POSIX for that reason I didn't use it in the first place but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Because brace expansion is performed *before* variable substitution, `{1..$n}` will not work as one would like and there are [good reasons to avoid `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead#17529221).  A simple solution is to fix the filenames so that they sort in order.

Consider these files:

```
$ ls
page_10.jpg  page_1.jpg  page_2.jpg  page_3.jpg  page_4.jpg  page_5.jpg  page_6.jpg  page_7.jpg  page_8.jpg  page_9.jpg
```

By prepending zeros to the single-digit file names, we can make them sort as you want:

```
$ for f in ./page_[0-9].jpg; do mv "$f" "./page_0${f#./page_}"; done
$ ls
page_01.jpg  page_02.jpg  page_03.jpg  page_04.jpg  page_05.jpg  page_06.jpg  page_07.jpg  page_08.jpg  page_09.jpg  page_10.jpg
```

Now you can use:

```
convert *.jpg out.pdf
```

#### Converting 2 digits to 3

As [smeterlink](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73244/smeterlink) points out, the above can be extended to convert 2 digits to 3:

```
for f in ./page_[0-9][0-9].jpg; do mv "$f" "./page_0${f#./page_}"; done
```

As an example, and using the files as above:

```
$ for f in ./page_[0-9][0-9].jpg; do mv "$f" "./page_0${f#./page_}"; done
$ ls
page_001.jpg  page_002.jpg  page_003.jpg  page_004.jpg  page_005.jpg  page_006.jpg  page_007.jpg  page_008.jpg  page_009.jpg  page_010.jpg
```

Comment: +1. `rename` can also be used for this.   e.g. `rename 's/^(\d+)\.png$/sprintf("%03i.png", $1)/e' *.png`.  This requires the perl `rename` utility (sometimes known as `file-rename`), not the much less capable `rename` in util-linux.

Comment: @cas Yes, for my own use, perl's rename is my first choice. If it weren't for some distributions having chosen the util-linux utility as their default and the naming uncertainty  (`rename` vs `file-rename` vs `prename`) on other distributions, it would be what I would recommend here.  It would be nice if the distributions could sort this out and develop a standard.

Comment: IMO the perl rename is standard, util-linux's rename is just an impostor :)   I've just got into the habit of mentioning that there are two entirely different programs called `rename` whenever I refer to it.   The fact that the perl rename can do things like this (regexp replace with a sprintf function call) is why i don't even consider util-linux's rename to be at all useful.

Comment: Thanks great. If there were 3 numeric digits it's very similar:
`for f in ./page_[0-9][0-9].jpg; do mv "$f" "./page_0${f#./page_}"; done`

Comment: @Smeterlink Yes, exactly right.  (I've just added that to the answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion is performed before variable substitution thus you need `eval` if you want it the other way round:

```
eval convert page_{1..$N}.jpg out.pdf
```

An alternative is to sort the expanded file names:

```
convert $(echo page_*.jpg | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n -k 2 -t _) out.pdf
```

Comment: Q is ambiguous but if the number isn't at the beginning of the line you need e.g. `sort -nk1.6` (or `-k1.6n`).

Comment: @HaukeLaging Second example does not work, results in  `page_1.jpg page_10.jpg page_2.jpg page_3.jpg page_4.jpg page_5.jpg page_6.jpg page_7.jpg page_8.jpg page_9.jpg`

Comment: @Smeterlink That is very strange. Not only because it does work for me but because `-n` is numeric sort. Are you using GNU `sort`? Mine is sort (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Comment: @HaukeLaging yes I'm using GNU Coreutils. The sort only works if the file starts with a number like `1.png 10.png 2.png` but doesn't if it starts with a letter which is the case. Did you even try the command yourself is you're just guessing? Post a screenshot.

Comment: @Smeterlink Indeed, I was sloppy and used not the correct file names for my test case. I have corrected the `sort` call.